# Java Not able to create a file in windows shared folder from Linux

Tags: java, linux, redhat

I am trying to create a file in a shared folder using the below code. I am able to do it when i run this code on windows. But however when i run the same code on linux it is not working.

In liunx it is creating a file named "\192.168.1.102\share\1.pdf" in the folder where i run this java code instead of creating a file 1.pdf in the shared folder "\192.168.1.102\share\".

It seems like while running on Linux the server was not identifying the path as a shared location, Instead it reads that as it's local path.

Are there any other ways to create a file in the shared folder? Could anyone please help me in resolving this?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s1 ="\\\\192.168.1.102\\share";
        try{

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(s1+"\\1.pdf");
            fos.write(("Testing Success").getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        File file = new File(s1);
        System.out.println(file.exists());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux simply doesn't support `\\ip\folder` path syntax.

You have to mount you shared folder before use.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enough permissions to write file on the shared folder. Or try running Jar of your code as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Please use java function File.separator instead of "\" in file path to make it platform independent.

As Windows support "\\" and linux supports "/".

(2) Check you have permission to write on that directory by using **chmod** command.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the file-system is properly mounted in the path you're using, the code won't work cross-platform because paths in Windows use `\` as a segment separator, while paths in Linux use `/`.

You should use cross-platform code to generate paths. The `File` class has a static `String` member called `separator` that will have the correct value for the platform.

```
String myPath = File.separator + "home" + File.separator + "bob"
```

The above will produce `\home\bob` in Windows, `/home/bob` in Linux/OSX

Comment: It is only part of a problem `//192.168.1.102/share/1.pdf` won't work either.

Comment: That's why I said _"assuming the file-system is properly mounted"_ :) the path is syntactically valid.

Comment: @slezica Can you suggest me how to properly mount a file-system in Linux .. When i tried i am getting "mount Error 112 Server is down"